# Why using left hand is forbidden?

Tags: belief, rituals

This question may seem silly. I want to know the reason why using a left hand during our daily life and in rituals. I have even seen some people who say not to accept anything with left hand. Some also say while you are wearing something new like a shirt or shoe, insert your right limb first. There are some parents who force their left handed children to change to right. Lord Hanuman enters Lanka with his **left foot** first as an enemy. I'm aware of that story. Arjuna was an ambidextrous person (see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8615/was-arjuna-left-handed) question for more) . 
But no one prevented him being a left handed and none punished him. More over many of us admire him due to this quality.

Can anyone say why people prevent their children to be left-handed?

Please post answers with valid reason but *not* *with generalized reasons*.  There is a [similar question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-significance-of-the-right-hand?rq=1) with accepted answer but it does not cite scriptural references.

Comment: 90% of the population is right handed. The left hand is reserved for cleaning yourself. As such it became associated with things unclean.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Namaskram Swamiji. But during performing vandanam to the Bhagawan, our both hands unite. Then why is it only limited to cleaning purposes?

Comment: @SreeCharan if you look into the Baphomet it also seems to demonstrate that the left hand path is associated with females and therefore not as holy.  Females are not as common to be priest and other things.  Not a great argument but valid.

Comment: **Bad Englsih** I just wanna keep it short because of my Shortage of knowledge. Left hand is Seen as bad luck and right is as good luck.Not only in Hindu culture's this is same in a lot of cultures. Ex:Shake hand is given with Right and many others.

Comment: Related [What is the significance of the right hand?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-significance-of-the-right-hand)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes. I have mentioned that in the question too. But I am looking for answer with any scriptural basis. Quotes, discourses of a scholar would also be fine.